# Safely Using Magento's Pre-configuration Events

Tags: php, oop, events, magento

In the Magento Ecommerce System, there are three events that fire before the system is fully bootstrapped

```
resource_get_tablename    
core_collection_abstract_load_before
core_collection_abstract_load_after
```

These events also fire **after** Magento has bootstrapped.

What's a safe and elegant (and maybe event Mage core team blessed) way to detect **when** Magento has fully bootstrapped so you may safely use these events?

If you attempt to use certain features in the pre-bootstrapped state, the entire request will 404.  The [best I've come up with](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events) (self-link for context) so far is something like this

```
class Packagename_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function observerMethod($observer)
    {
        $is_safe = true;
        try
        {
            $store = Mage::app()->getSafeStore();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $is_safe = false;
        }
        if(!$is_safe)
        {
            return;
        }     

        //if we're still here, we could initialize store object
        //and should be well into router initialization
    }

}
```

but that's a little unwieldy.

Comment: Since you cite a request specifically, I'd be curious to know what you would want to accomplish in these events that couldn't be done in a much cleaner sense in [`controller_front_init_before`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L128)

Comment: @benmarks — one specific example: Commerce Bug collects collection data using the collection events.  However, every commerce bug observer also respects the On/Off setting stored in the configuration.  If Commerce Bug is set to not collect data, I want the observer to bail and not collect that data.  That means checking the configuration, which you can't do from a pre-bootstrap observer. So I need to check if we're in an early bootstrap state before checking the configuration. The problem is those events fire early, but have uses when they fire late.  Did that make sense?

Comment: Yep. That makes sense. Collecting collections. Inception!

Comment: How about checking `Mage::registry('controller')`? If it isn't null, then front controller instance exists.

Comment: @alanstorm perhaps the thing to do is to collect data and then 86 as soon as the module settings *can* be determined.

Comment: You could manually read the settings you need from the database, which is trivial :-)

Comment: Would checking if the config object exists work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any event tailored for that.

You could add you own and file a pull request / Magento ticket to include a good one.

Until then I think the only way is to use one of the events you found and do some checks on how far Magento is initialized.

Did you try to get `Mage::app()->getStores()`? This might save you from the Exception catching.

Comment: @cmuench: What's the advantage? We have to know a specific code or id then.